# Replacing a String Pattern with another sequence in unix

Tags: unix, awk

I want replace the String `TaskID_1` with a sequence starting from `1001` and this `TaskID_1` can exists any many number of lines in my input file.
Similarly i need to replace all occurrences of `TASKID_2` in my input file with next sequence value `1002`.

Input file:

```
12345|45345|TaskID_1|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|TaskID_1|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|TaskID_2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|TaskID_2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|TaskID_1|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|TaskID_2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|TaskID_3|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|TaskID_4|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|TaskID_3|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

The output file should look like:

```
12345|45345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|1004|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { $3=1000 + NR }1' file
```

Or less verbosely:

```
awk -F '|' '{ $3=1000 + NR }1' OFS='|' file
```

Results:

```
12345|45345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|1004|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|1005|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|1006|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|1007|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|1008|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|1009|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

For the first example, the file separator and output file separator are set to a single pipe character. This is set in the `BEGIN` block, so that it is executed only once, and not on every line of input. We then set the third column to be equal to 1000 plus an incrementing variable. We could use `++i` as this variable, but we could instead use `NR` (which is short for record number/line number) and this would therefore avoid the need to create an extra variable. The `1` on the end enables printing by default. A more verbose solution would look like:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { $3=1000 + NR; print }' file
```

---

***EDIT:***

Using the updated data file, try:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { sub(/.*_/,"",$3); $3+=1000 }1' file
```

Results:

```
12345|45345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|1004|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

Comment: **+1** ... yup, that's just about exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: +1 darn, beat me to it (the last solution above, that is) :-).

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 5.394 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

A Perl solution using Steve's logic of adding 1000:

```
perl -pne 's/TaskID_(\d+)/$1+1000/e;' file
```

This replaces the 'TaskID_n' with 1000+n.   'e' is used to evaluate the replacement.

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 6.363 seconds. A bit slower than awk but easier to understand if you know regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I can't come up with a better solution than the one steve suggested in awk.

So here's a worse solution, using only bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='|'

while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6; do
    printf '%s|%s|%d|%s|%s|%s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$((${f3#*_}+1000))" "$f4" "$f5" "$f6"
done < input
```

It's "worse" only because it'll be much slower than awk, which is fast and efficient with this sort of problem.

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 66 seconds. Very slow, but still ok to use and easy to understand.

Comment: If you replace $((++n)) by $((${f3#*_}+1000)) then it is what the question wanted. And the time I measured was for the corrected version.

Comment: Oh, and you have to replace `f1 f2 _ f4 f5 f6` by `f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6`.

Comment: @erik - right you are, I missed the relationship between TaskID when I answered this last year.  I've updated my answer with your fix.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `TaskID_` with `100`, this is super easy with `sed` for single digit IDs:

```
$ sed 's/TaskID_/100/' file
12345|45345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|1004|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
```

To store this change back to the file use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/TaskID_/100/' file
```

*Note: this works for `TaskID_[0-9]` if you want `TaskID_23` mapped to `1023` then this won't, this would map `TaskID_23` to `10023`.*

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 0.861 seconds. Fastest, but only for 1000 to 1009.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F"\|" -lane '$F[2]=~s/.*_/100/g;print join("|",@F)' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
12345|45345|TaskID_1|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|TaskID_1|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|TaskID_2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|TaskID_2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|TaskID_1|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|TaskID_2|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|TaskID_3|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|TaskID_4|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|TaskID_3|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
> perl -F"\|" -lane '$F[2]=~s/.*_/100/g;print join("|",@F)' temp
12345|45345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1245|425345|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
1234|25345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|65345|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
123425|15325|1001|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
11345|55315|1002|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
6345|15345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
72345|25345|1004|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
9345|411345|1003|dksj|kdjfdsjf|12
>
```

Comment: Time for a file with 1M lines: 7.463 seconds. Slowest (except bash), and only for 1000 to 1009.